# Помогите написать программу

Tags: java

Даны целые a1, a2,…,an. Найти наибольшее значение, содержащееся в последовательности чисел a1,
a2,…,an после выбрасывания из нее:
а) одного из членов со значением max(a1, a2,…,an);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static int getSecondMax(int[] a) {
    if(a.length < 2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    int absoluteMax = Math.max(a[0], a[1]); 
    int secondMax = Math.min(a[0], a[1]);
    for(int i = 2; i < a.length; i++) {
        if(a[i] > secondMax) {
            if(a[i] > absoluteMax) {
                secondMax = absoluteMax;
                absoluteMax = a[i];
            } else {
                secondMax = a[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return secondMax;
}
```

Если что не понятно по логике - спрашивайте

Comment: это зло - вот так писать `int absoluteMax = a[0] > a[1] ? a[0] : a[1];`

Comment: Почему так? Одно же логическое суждение, если вы про скобки. Правьте, если считаете, что так понятнее. Я возражать не буду

Comment: @Miron Math.max

Comment: Хорошее предложение, исправил